# Asterisk ami deleting of certain extension

Tags: php, asterisk

I have custom class for work with asterisk ami via php.
Using [asterisk docs](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+UpdateConfig),
I tried this:

```
$a->write("Action: updateconfig\r\nReload: yes\r\nSrcfilename: extensions.conf\r\nDstfilename: extensions.conf\r\nAction-000000: delete\r\nCat-000000: test\r\nVar-000000: exten");
```

This delets all extensions from test category. I need to delete certain extension.
In docs there is a Match field, but it's not really clear for me what should I match with in extension value.
I have an extension:

```
exten => 999,1,Dial(SIP/Bob)
```

I tried this:

```
$a->write("Action: updateconfig\r\nReload: yes\r\nSrcfilename: extensions.conf\r\nDstfilename: extensions.conf\r\nAction-000000: delete\r\nCat-000000: test\r\nVar-000000: exten\r\nValue-000000: 999");
```

this:

```
$a->write("Action: updateconfig\r\nReload: yes\r\nSrcfilename: extensions.conf\r\nDstfilename: extensions.conf\r\nAction-000000: delete\r\nCat-000000: test\r\nVar-000000: exten\r\nMatch-000000: 999");
```

this:

```
$a->write("Action: updateconfig\r\nReload: yes\r\nSrcfilename: extensions.conf\r\nDstfilename: extensions.conf\r\nAction-000000: delete\r\nCat-000000: test\r\nVar-000000: exten\r\nMatch-000000: Bob");
```

First variant still delets all extensions from category and other two with Match
return error message: `Delete did not complete successfully`

How can I delete certain extensions then?

Answer (score 1):

I had to write full extension value in Match field, without >
`999,1,Dial(SIP/Bob)` like this.